# Prove $\int_1^\infty (\ln x)^{-x} dx$ diverges.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Prove $\int_1^\infty (\ln x)^{-x} dx$ diverges. I don't think evaluating it is even a choice. Pretty clearly I need to find a function to compare it to, which also diverges, but it's hard since even a small change such as $\int_1^\infty (\ln 1.001x)^{-x} dx$ makes it converge. Due to this, I haven't considered other methods of approximation such as integration by parts or approximating the function as a taylor series. Thoughts and hints?

Comment: How did you get that $\int_1^{\infty} (\ln(0.001x))^{-x} dx$ converges? The integrand is poorly defined for most $x < 1000$.

Comment: My mistake, I meant anything greater than 1 as coefficient. I should also specify ln

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $0\lt\log(1+u)\lt u$ for $0\lt u$, and observe

$$\int_1^\infty(\ln x)^{-x}\,dx=\int_0^\infty{du\over(\ln(1+u))^{1+u}}\gt\int_0^1{du\over u^{1+u}}\gt\int_0^1{du\over u}$$

(since $u^u\lt1$ for $0\lt u\lt1$, to obtain the last inequality).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is around $x=1$ since
$$\big[\log (x)\big]^{-x}\sim\frac 1{x-1}+\frac{1}{2}-\log (x-1)+\cdots$$

Comment: Coiuld you clarify a bit more? Why does it matter if it's approaching 0 in the denom? At that specific value maybe the integrand could approach infinity, but also it's for an infinitely small $dx$ right?

Comment: Integrate the rhs between $1$ and $2$

Comment: Lastly, how did you get that approximated form?